# Click on a button and advance to the limit of the window in tinker

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying to learn python from a book. I'm trying to do an exercise with tinker. Click on a button and advance to the limit of the window. Then always by clicking on the same button to advance the circle to the other side of the window. Thanks for your help.

```
from tkinter import *

def avance(n, g):
    global x, y, step
    # nouvelles coordonnées :
    x[n] = x[n] + g # deplacement de l'axe des x
    # déplacement du dessin dans le canevas :
    can.coords(bille[n], x[n]-10, y[n]-10, x[n]+10, y[n]+10)

    # affichage pour info du x:
    Info.configure(text="Coordonnée x = " + str(x[n]))
    
    i = 0 
             
    if x[n] >= 50:
        while i <= 400:
            step = +20
            i = i+5
            
    if x[n] >= 400:
        step = -20
        i = i-5

    return step          

    


def go():
    avance(0, step)


bille = [0]      # liste servant à mémoriser les références du cercle
x = [50]     # X de départ
y = [100]    # y de départ
step = 0   # "pas" de déplacement initial

# Construction de la fenêtre :
fen = Tk()
fen.title("avance quand on clique jusqu'à la limite de la fenêtre et revient")


Info = Label(fen) # pour afficher l'info du x
Info.grid(row=3, column=0)

# Canvas :
can = Canvas(fen, bg="white", width=400, height=200)
can.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
bille[0] = can.create_oval(x[0]-10, y[0]-10, x[0]+10, y[0]+10,
                           fill="blue")

# bouton avance :
f = Frame(fen)
f.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10)

Button(f, text="Go", fg='blue', command=go).pack(side=LEFT)

fen.mainloop()
```

the problem is that when the ball reaches the limit (first while loop) when it starts the second loop, it returns to the conditions of the first.

sorry for my English

thank for help

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.
here is my solution

```
from tkinter import *

def avance(n, g):
    global x, y, step
    # nouvelles coordonnées :
    x[n] = x[n] + g # deplacement de l'axe des x
    # déplacement du dessin dans le canevas :
    can.coords(bille[n], x[n]-10, y[n]-10, x[n]+10, y[n]+10)

    # affichage pour info du x:
    Info.configure(text="Coordonnée x = " + str(x[n]))   

    i = 0   
    
    if 5 >= x[n] < 400:  # 5 superieur ou egale à x et x inferieur à 400 , execute la ligne suivante
        step=+20
        return step
    if 5 <= x[n] >= 400: # 5 inferieur ou egale à x et x superieur ou egale à 400 , execute la ligne suivante    
        step = -20
        return step
        # x egale 50 execute le premier if..

def go():
    avance(0, step)


step = 0 # variable pour le pas d'avancement
bille = [0]      # liste servant à mémoriser les références du cercle
x = [5]     # X de départ
y = [100]    # y de départ
  # "pas" de déplacement initial

# Construction de la fenêtre :
fen = Tk()
fen.title("avance quand on clique jusqu'à la limite de la fenêtre et revient")


Info = Label(fen) # pour afficher l'info du x
Info.grid(row=3, column=0)

# Canvas :
can = Canvas(fen, bg="white", width=400, height=200)
can.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
bille[0] = can.create_oval(x[0]-10, y[0]-10, x[0]+10, y[0]+10,
                           fill="blue")

# bouton avance :
f = Frame(fen)
f.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10)

Button(f, text="Go", fg='blue', command=go).pack(side=LEFT)

fen.mainloop()
```